# Separating an unknown amount of hyphens in java?

Tags: java

Good day, guys,
I'm working on a program which requires me to input a name (E.g Patrick-Connor-O'Neill). The name can be composed of as many names as possible, so not necessarily restricted to solely 3 as seen in the example above.But the point of the program is to return the initials back so in this case PCO. I'm writing to ask for a little clarification. I need to separate the names out from the hyphens first, right? Then I need to take the first character of the names and print that out?
Anyway, my question is basically how do I separate the string if I don't know how much is inputted? I get that if it's only like two terms I would do:

```
final String s = "Before-After";
final String before = s.split("-")[0]; // "Before"
```

I did attempt to do the code, and all I have so far is:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class main {
     public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         String input = scan.nextLine();
         String[] x = input.split("-");
         int u =0;
         for(String i : x) {
             String y = input.split("-")[u];
             u++;
         }
     }
}
```

I'm taking a crash course in programming, so easy concepts are hard for me.Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to split it a second time. By doing `String[] x = input.split("-");` you have an Array of Strings. Now you can iterate over them which you already do with the enhanced for loop. It should look like this

```
String[] x = input.split("-");
String initials = "";
for (String name : x) {
    initials += name.charAt(0);
}
System.out.println(initials);
```

Here are some Java Docs for the used methods

- [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))
- [`String#charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int))
- [Assignment operator `+=`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

Comment: Oh I see, can I just ask what the"initials += names.charArt(0);" does? If I understand the logic behind the codes I remember them more easily (also thank you so much).

Comment: @E.af I added some links at the bottom. The `+=` is an assignment operator and `charAt` a method to get a character at a certain index from a String. Zero is the first character.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without splitting the string by using `String.indexOf` to find the next `-`; then just append the subsequent character to the initials:

```
String initials = "" + input.charAt(0);
int next = -1;
while (true) {
  next = input.indexOf('-', next + 1);
  if (next < 0) break;
  initials += input.charAt(next + 1);
}
```

(There are lots of edge cases not handled here; omitted to get across the main point of the approach).

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
String test = "abs-bcd-cde-fgh-lik";
    String[] splitArray = test.split("-");
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
        stringBuffer.append(splitArray[i].charAt(0));
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuffer);
}
```

Using StringBuffer will save your memory as, if you use String a new object will get created every time you modify it.

Comment: Use StringBuilder (as per your comment) not StringBuffer (as per your code)

Answer (score 0):

In your `for-each` loop append first character of all the elements of String array into an output String to get the initials:

```
String output = "";

for(String i : x) {    
    output = output + y.charAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String output = "";
    String input = "Patrick-Connor-O'Neil-Saint-Patricks-Day";

    String[] brokenInput = input.split("-");

    for (String temp : brokenInput) {
        if (!temp.equals(""))
            output = output + temp.charAt(0);
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could totally try something like this (a little refactor of your code):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String input = "";
        System.out.println("What's your name?");

        input = scan.nextLine();

        String[] x = input.split("-");
        int u =0;

            for(String i : x) {
                String y = input.split("-")[u];
                u++;
                System.out.println(y);
            }
    }
}
```

I think it's pretty easy and straightforward from here if you want to simply isolate the initials. If you are new to Java make sure you use a lot of System.out since it helps you a lot with debugging.

Good coding.

EDIT: You can use @Mohit Tyagi 's answer with mine to achieve the full thing if you are cheating :P